# Movie in which a boy found an alien and became its friend (not ET)

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

This movie has a boy that found an alien somewhere and then becomes friends with it, but then the alien gets attacked by military or something like that. The boy finds the alien in the woods then tries to show one of his friends or family members but then the military starts shooting at them and they catch the boy but not the alien and the alien helps him try to escape.

P. S. This is not ET...

Comment: No not E.T but thanks.

Comment: More information, please. Any specific scenes you might remember? Original language of the movie?

Comment: Without more to go on, this film could match any one of [a dozen or more](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InnocentAliens)

Comment: I updated hope you can find it and help me out

Comment: @Shadow - Could you work your way through the checklists here [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) as it sounds like there's more info that you could add.

Answer (score 6):

It could be **Mac and Me** (1988):

There is an alien coming from another planet. He becomes friend with a human (disabled) boy and he is chased by the army.

- [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_and_Me)
- [IMDb page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095560/)

[image: Movie still: an alien on th eboy's shoulders, blue background]